# Maximum and minimum caps for list values in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values and I'd like to set the maximum value of any element in the list to 255 and the minimum value to 0 while leaving those within the range unchanged.

```
oldList = [266, 40, -15, 13]

newList = [255, 40, 0, 13]
```

Currently I'm doing

```
for i in range(len(oldList)):
    if oldList[i] > 255:
        oldList[i] = 255
    if oldList[i] < 0:
        oldList[i] = 0
```

or similarly with `newList.append(oldList[i])`.

But there has to be a better way than that, right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) functions:

```
>>> min(266, 255)
255
>>> max(-15, 0)
0
```

---

```
>>> oldList = [266, 40, -15, 13]
>>> [max(min(x, 255), 0) for x in oldList]
[255, 40, 0, 13]
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option is is [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.clip([266, 40, -15, 13], 0, 255)
array([255,  40,   0,  13])
```

Comment: is this faster that the `max(min())`  approche?

Answer (score 2):

You can use map and lambda in Python.
Example:

```
newList= map(lambda y: max(0,min(255,y)), oldList)
```

You can even nest them if it's a multidimensional list.
Example:

```
can=map(lambda x: map(lambda y: max(0.0,min(10.0,y)), x), can)
can=[[max(min(u,10.0),0.0) for u in yy] for yy in can]
```

However I think using the for loop as mentioned above is faster than map lambda for this case. I tried it on a rather large list (2 million float) and got-

```
time python trial.py

real    0m14.060s
user    0m10.542s
sys     0m0.594s
```

Using a for and-

```
time python trial.py

real    0m15.813s
user    0m12.243s
sys     0m0.627s
```

Using map lambda.

Another alternative is-

```
newList=np.clip(oldList,0,255)
```

It is convenient for any dimensionality and very fast.

```
time python trial.py

real    0m10.750s
user    0m7.148s
sys     0m0.735s
```